# Dockerize CMS and NextJS and handle depedencies (NextJS needs CMS running to build)

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, strapi

### Context

I am trying to dockerize my app which is made off a headless CMS (Strpi) and a client NextJS.

NextJS needs to have my CMS running in order to build (it's fetching the content there on port 1337)

### Code

**My docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./server/strapi_portfolio.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/strapi_portfolio.sql
    networks:
      - portfolio-network

  portfolio-strapi:
    build:
      context : ./server
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - ./portfolio-strapi:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - portfolio-network

    depends_on:
      - db

  portfolio-nextjs:
    build:
      context : ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./portfolio-nextjs:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - portfolio-network
    depends_on:
      - portfolio-strapi

networks:
  portfolio-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**NextJS Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18-alpine as builder

WORKDIR "/app"

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile --production=true

COPY . .
RUN npm run build-prod

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Strapi (CMS) Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR "/app"
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM node:18-alpine AS runner

COPY --from=builder /app/package.json /app/package-lock.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./

RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile --omit=dev

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

### What I tried

- I tried the `depends_on` functionnality of docker but it's not working, even with healthchecks.
  **Yes the CMS build is triggered before but my NextJS app is not waiting for it to be served before building**
- I tried to create a npm script that waits for my api to be available before running the build script :

```js
const MAX_RETRIES = 10;
let retries = 0;

const waitForStrapi = async () => {
  while (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
    console.log(`[ATTEMPT ${retries}] Trying to reach Strapi...`);
    try {
      await fetch("http://localhost:1337");
      console.log("Strapi is ready!");
      break;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Waiting for Strapi...");
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 30000));
    }
    retries++;
  }
};

waitForStrapi();
console.log("[ERROR - Couldn't connect to Strapi]");
```

My CMS image is fully built BUT is never running (so `http://localhost:1337` can never be resolved) and I don't know why...

Am I missing something or may I not have the right philosophy to achieve this ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the "command" section of the docker-compose file, so it would look something like this:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./server/strapi_portfolio.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/strapi_portfolio.sql
    networks:
      - portfolio-network

  portfolio-strapi:
    build:
      context : ./server
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - ./portfolio-strapi:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - portfolio-network
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: npm run start

  portfolio-nextjs:
    build:
      context : ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./portfolio-nextjs:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - portfolio-network
    depends_on:
      - portfolio-strapi
    command: npm run start

networks:
  portfolio-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Man I love you ! To understand, what does it change ? it tells docker that a container is ready when it executes "npm run start" ?

Comment: CMD does not execute anything at build time, but specifies the intended command for the image, and the command in the docker-compose file actually runs it, when the container starts